# How do I enter multiple locations in USA on an ESTA application (same trip)?

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I'm travelling to Orlando, then travelling to 2 other states on my trip via airplanes—how do I enter these on my ESTA application?

Comment: No need to. Once you've entered the US under the visa waiver program, you can travel to any states as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ESTA FAQ](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/esta.html), you don't even need to have your destination planned or any transport/lodging booked to apply, and you can change itinerary afterward.

Their webserver won't accept the direct link, so click the main page link above, scroll down, and click "VIEW ALL TOPICS."  Then expand "Completing your application" and click the third entry about travel plans.

Comment: So I see.  I didn't look closely at the tiny image dishonestly designed to look like a government agency's seal.  Nor the fine print disclaimer on the bottom, which I really think should not be sufficient to avoid prosecution.  Dishonest jerks.

Comment: I have changed it to the correct URI which does say the same  thing more tersely.